# How to launch gui application as root on login?

Tags: openbox, autostart

I've got a gui application that runs a couple of scripts, which require root access. Normally it is run with sudo, but I've modified the scripts (by running only commands that require root access with sudo prefix) so that the main thing works if launched normally.

One occassion when it doesn't work is when I use openbox autostart script to run it on login. It launches fine, but scripts fail to work and sudo.log shows no activity during that period.

Is there any way to make this setup work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As far as I can tell openbox won't allow sudo (or gksudo or anything of the sort) in its autostart. `chmod +s` on the executable is the way I forced running the application as root. It also didn't work at first, because in qt5 (which was used to build the app) you cannot use suid by default - I had to change it in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gksudo instead of sudo to run GUI apps from terminal as root.